# Linguagem script para JVM e DVM

Tags: java, android, scripting, portabilidade

Pretendo usar uma linguagem script acoplada a aplicativos Java SE, meu receio é desenvolver algo e depois mais tarde tenha dificuldades em portar isso para plataforma Android. Não sou profissional na área, mas sei da importância da portabilidade, pois o mundo mobile hoje é realidade há muito tempo, e como faço as vezes alguns utilitários para ajudar em algumas tarefas do dia a dia, com certeza gostaria de porta-los para o Android (OS mais popular atualmente quanto aos mobile).

Vi que o Google não incluiu o pacote javax e nele nós temos o ScriptEngine. Hoje pesquisei e achei uma alternativa, o [BSF](https://github.com/apache/commons-bsf) da Apache. O problema é que não sei se esse negocio tá ainda em desenvolvimento ativo...

O que vocês sugerem? Eu nunca mexi com jogos (também não é meu interesse aqui), mas sei que a galera costuma usar Lua para scripting (para estender as funcionalidades de aplicativos de forma a não necessitar recompilar todo ele). E no Android, como vocês fazem?

---

**Mais detalhes**

Necessito de uma linguagem script porque:

- às vezes faço web scraping e necessito alterar o código com frequência;
- faço testes com a Wikipédia e tenho pretensão em testar algoritmos para detectar vandalismo (frequentemente tem que ser atualizado);
- gosto de ter a disposição um REPL (Read Eval Print Loop) para prototipação, etc.

Uma vez anos atrás fiz um teste de Java SE com Rhino, usando ECMAScript mesmo, achei bacana porque pude desenvolver até um chamado REPL no aplicativo, foi muito bom para prototipação.

Comment: Esta um pouco confuso, o ScriptEngine serve para rodar scripts ECMAScript, basta você importar o pacote do ScriptEngine e compilar, agora Lua não é pra construir jogos, ele tem a capacidade de editar alguns jogos de ROMs mas ae é outra coisa. Se quer criar jogos recomendo que use uma ferramenta propria para isto como Unity3d (suporta 2d também).

Comment: Lua pelo que eu sei @GuilhermeNascimento não é para criar jogos, não disse isso, disse que ele é usado como linguagem script. No Android não existe ScriptEngine.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o ScriptEngine também não serve apenas para rodar ECMAScript, ele roda muito mais linguagens compativeis com JSR 223. Veja http://stackoverflow.com/a/14864450/3697611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem muitas linguagens que podem ser emuladas no Java, mas quando se fala em portabilidade para jogos o problema vai para outro nível. Alguns exemplos de diferença:

- Você não apenas executará uma mesma linguagem como precisará que ambas as plataformas disponibilizem acesso a recursos gráficos e outros requisitos para desenvolvimento de jogos através das mesmas API.
- O item acima implica em que você não vai poder usar bibliotecas e frameworks comuns para desenvolvimento de jogos, a não ser que ela esteja disponível para as plataformas almejadas.
- As diferenças no tamanho da tela geralmente exigem imagens diferentes para cada resolução.
- As interfaces de entrada dos dispositivos também são bem diferentes, por exemplo, mouse contra tela de toque.

Em resumo, mesmo que o código seja 100% portável, ainda vai haver muitos aspectos que exigem duas implementações distintas.

Claro que as diferenças podem ser diminuídas impondo algumas limitações no Jogo, tal como exibir gráficos com menos qualidade na versão desktop, mas coloquei os pontos acima apenas para tentar ressaltar alguns aspectos que você pode estar ignorando.

Quanto a linguagem utilizada, é verdade que é complicado fazer **scripting em Android, mas há, pelo menos, duas opções:

1. **JavaScript no [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).** Tenho alguns colegas que criaram jogos simples usando essa plataforma. Tem até [um tutorial](http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/01/18/my-first-mobile-game-in-html-with-phonegap-build/) que dá algumas ideias. Confesso que não sou usuário dessa tecnologia, mas ao que parece [é possível criar aplicações híbridas](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-phonegap-desktop-app-v0-1-1-beta/) para dispositivos móveis e desktop. Claro que o desempenho dessas aplicações nunca será capaz de competir com código nativo.
2. **Java.** Se o seu foco é limitado a Android e desktop com Java SE, não há razão técnica alguma para você precisar de uma linguagem de script por cima. As razões porque as pessoas usam Lua em cima de C e C++ é para ter uma linguagem de mais alto nível enquanto ainda podem usufruir do alto desempenho dessas linguagens quando necessário, só que Java já é de mais alto nível do que aquelas linguagens e suficientemente fácil de trabalhar, enquanto ainda provê um desempenho razoável, algo como um meio termo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas orientações @utluiz! Quanto ao comentário de número 2, eu necessito de uma linguagem script por que as vezes eu faço web scraping, dessa forma fica muito mais fácil por exemplo eu atualizar meu código de scraping por scripts porque se for por compilação a todo momento precisaria mudar meu código e compilar (as páginas da internet mudam frequentemente).

Comment: Olha, gostei muito da ideia do PhoneGap até porque já brinquei com nodejs e achei muito bacana! Sabe se nós podemos usar npm com esse phonegap? Como funciona o gerenciamento de dependências?

Comment: @guiwp Parece que é possível usar com o `npm`. Veja http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/

Comment: Funciona sim, pelo que eu vi é só ser compatível com cordova, ex.: http://node-modules.com/search?u=cordova&q=camera+ecosystem%3Acordova .